# Janrain settings not getting saved in Drupal (Error Contacting Engage)

Tags: php, apache, drupal, xampp, janrain

This is happening in our local web server installed using XAMPP

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. Registered the account with Janrain.com
2. Created the app "testapp" and configured the engage application with the
   providers Yahoo!, Twitter and Linked In.
3. Downloaded the Janrain Engage Drupal 7 module from the Janrain website
4. Installed this module in my local web application.
5. Activated the plugin and in the Janrain Drupal settings page, I entered the following details - a) Engage Server & b) API Key
6. After giving these details, clicked on the "Save Configuration" button. Finally, instead of the information being saved, we get the error message
   **"Error message Error contacting Engage. Please verify your internet connection and try again."**
7. I tried to look in to the code, the below line was creating the issue

   `$lookup = RPX::lookup($api_key, $rpx_server);`
8. Checked the "lookup" function code and found that I was able to connect with the Engage server but some problem with the response.

In this "lookup" function, we are getting the below JSON response

```
stdClass Object
(
[request] => POST https:// rpxnow.com /plugin/lookup_rp HTTP/1.0
Referer: http:// localhost /testapp
User-Agent: Janrain_Engage_Drupal_Module
Proxy-Authorization: Basic
Host: rpxnow.com Content-Length: 105 [data] => "" [protocol] => HTTP/1.0 [status_message] => OK [code] => 200)
```

9) Found that "data" facet in the JSON response was missing

Please let me know what is the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a web server configuration issue... the drupal_http_request() function is probably failing to run. There may be any number of fixes depending on what is specifically happening. More info here: https://drupal.org/node/222454